# Use of natural logarithm transformation on weighted index series

Tags: logarithms, power-series, exponentiation

I have a value computed as sum of powers, e.g. $x^5+y^8+z^2$.
The exponent represents the weight for variables, $x, y$ and $z$ in the example above.

Applying natural logarithm on $x^5+y^8+z^2$, I get a graph that more accurately describes what I'm looking for.

What I need help with is understanding why that is: why applying the natural logarithm helps. Or should it be done differently?

Thank you.

Comment: $$\log(x^5+y^8+z^2) = 5 \log(x) + 8 \log(y) + 2 \log(z)$$

Comment: Thanks sunflower, I know that. I'm trying to understand why log(x) works.

Comment: By the way, you can't break the sum like that.